# Scraping Daraz.pk

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to scraping and i would like to **scrape** products and prices from daraz.pk . I learned from a tutorial and was able to scrape data from amazon but not able to do it in daraz.
Please can anyone tell me how get the laptop product name from this link: https://www.daraz.pk/gaming-laptops/?spm=a2a0e.home.cate_1_4.1.35e349375wfPov

i tried using response.css("c16H9d::text").extract() but not able to retrieve any data.
Regards

Comment: It uses JS to create output. I can handle it in R, is that ok for you?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1):

I have written this code for grooming category of Daraz.pkl. However, if you want to scrape other products, just add link of that page in Url and add required xpath below.

```py
import bs4 as bs
import re
from selenium import webdriver
name=[]
price=[]
url = 'https://www.daraz.pk/dog-grooming-supplies/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
for i in range(1,40):
  target_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div['+str(i)+']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a')
  target_prize=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div['+str(i)+']/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span')
name.append(target_name.text)
price.append(target_prize.text)


driver.quit()
print(name)
print(price)
```

Adjust the intend, if you find any problem and do let me know, if you find any problem